# Setting TextTrimming (CharacterEllipsis) in DataGrid's Cell

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I would like to apply TextTrimming property (CharacterEllipsis) to the text in WPF DataGrid cells.

[image: DataGrid cells without TextTrimming set]

I applied custom DataGridCell template as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671608/wpf-datagrid-how-do-i-set-columns-to-textwrap) (code below) and it works well, except for the Hyperlink columns like the first one in the picture), which now are empty.

[image: TextTrimming set on text columns, but hyperling column contents missing]

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="3" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I can see the difference in both column types in visual tree:
[image: Datagrid row in visual tree (when no custom template is applied)]

but don't understand how I can use this information to apply TextTrimming to TextBlock's columns of both type. Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally ended up with the following solution (more like a workaround, but it works fine):

1) I assigned an **x:Key** to the style in question and applied it as a **CellStyle** to all DataGridTextColumns that should have their contents trimmed and ellipsisized whenever they don't fit

2) To apply ellipsis trimming in DataGridHyperlinkColumns, in **App.xaml** I added the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>
</Style>
```

which will apply to all implicitly generated TextBlocks (as described in [CodeNaked's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812213/889779)). This might seem a bit overkill, but I can't see much difference in rendering performance and Hyperlinks are now trimmed as expected.